# Convert for loops into list comprehension

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I have a looping condition that I want to convert into list comprehension. I just want to learn how we can write complex for loops into a single line.

```
num = []
for i in range(2, numRows):
    row = []
    for j in range(i - 1):
        row.append(sum(num[-1][j:j + 2]))
    num.append([1] + row + [1])
```

I think the `list comprehension` can only be used with `if` `else` condition. Can we write regular expression inside? Can anyone show me if it is possible? The below code is not working for me.

```
row = []
[num.append([1] + row + [1]) row = [] [row.append(sum(num[-1][j:j + 2])) for j in range(i - 1)]for i in range(2, numRows)]
```

EDIT: My initial code for Pascal Triangle

```
class Solution(object):
    def generate(self, numRows):
        """
        :type numRows: int
        :rtype: List[List[int]]
        if numRows = 5
               [
                     [1],
                    [1,1],
                   [1,2,1],
                  [1,3,3,1],
                 [1,4,6,4,1]
               ]
        """

        num = [[1], [1, 1]]
        if numRows == 1:
            return num[0]
        elif numRows == 2:
            return num

        row = []
        for i in range(2, numRows):
            for j in range(i - 1):
                row.append(sum(num[-1][j:j + 2]))
            num.append([1] + row + [1])
            row = []

        return num
```

Comment: Why do you think that a list comprehension will provide you better readability here? Even if it were possible to do that in a list comp, it would likely be *harder* to read.

Comment: I am just trying to learn how can we covert complex `looping condition` into list comprehension. I think `readability` is not the appropriate word here.

Comment: For example `[i for i in words[index:]] for index, j in enumerate(words)]` but this is an easy one!

Comment: Technically, you can reproduce this with simply `row = []`, because you do that reassignment after every iteration of the outer loop, wiping everything out. Why are you doing that?

Comment: Just want to learn how we can write complex loops into a single line in Python.

Comment: And I'm saying that you _can_ write that whole thing in a single line, with `row = []`, because that reassignment every time through the loop throws away all the previous work, so that's what you end up with. Also, no, this particular structure minus the trailing `row = []` can't be a comprehension because it has references to itself (although I bet there's some awful hack to make it work).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Maybe it's a CodeGolf / another "smallest code" challenge.

Comment: The last line makes absolutely no sense `row = []`

Comment: Reset the `row` list

Comment: Oh, I see - the `num` that's not initialized is probably the main `list`, and the posted block is the content of a loop that isn't shown. In any case, `row = []` doesn't need to happen at the end of each iteration if it's already happening at the beginning.

Comment: Actually this is really good question but I badly framed it. That's why so many negatives, will modify once a reach home.

Comment: Hopefully there will be no more confusion.

Comment: I see now - `row = []` should appear exactly once, below `for i in range(2, numRows):`.

Comment: I've edited your code block into a more complete, sensible structure. Please look it over to ensure that it accurately represents your issue, and make any necessary changes.

Comment: Updated my whole code. My purpose was just to make it shorter by using list comprehension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to make Pascal's Triangle. For the code in your first code block to work you need to initialise `num` properly:

```
num = [[1,1]]
```

It's not practical* to generate Pascal's Triangle in a list comprehension because to generate each row you need to access the previous row. However, it's easy to do using a combination of a "traditional" `for` loop and a list comp that uses `zip` to create the pairs of numbers that need to be added.

```
def pascal(m):
    """ Build m rows of Pascal's triangle """
    row = [1]
    rows = [row]
    for i in xrange(m):
        #Generate next row from current row
        row = [x + y for x, y in zip([0] + row, row + [0])]
        rows.append(row)
    return rows

#test
width = 50
for row in pascal(10):
    print " ".join(["%3d" % x for x in row]).center(width)
```

**output**

```
                         1                        
                       1   1                      
                     1   2   1                    
                   1   3   3   1                  
                 1   4   6   4   1                
               1   5  10  10   5   1              
             1   6  15  20  15   6   1            
           1   7  21  35  35  21   7   1          
         1   8  28  56  70  56  28   8   1        
       1   9  36  84 126 126  84  36   9   1      
     1  10  45 120 210 252 210 120  45  10   1
```

I see in your list comp attempt that you're using `row.append`. Please don't do that. The `list.append` method returns `None`, so calling it in a list comp creates a list full of `None`s. Sure, that's legal Python, and in some circumstances you *may* be able to calculate the desired results that way, but most experienced Python programmers consider it to be bad practice to abuse list comps like that. Use them when you want the actual list they produce, not merely as a way to shoe-horn a `for` loop onto one line.

Don't get me wrong - I love list comprehensions and generator expressions. Although they can be a bit perplexing at first, once you're used to them they are succinct and compact. And list comps are slightly more efficient than using `.append` in a traditional `for` loop. However, deeply-nested / complicated list comps and gen expressions can be hard to read for even the most experienced Pythonista. So don't try to cram too much into them and don't hesitate to split them up into multiple stages if it makes the code more readable.

---

* It *is* actually possible to generate Pascal's Triangle in a list comp, using the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) formula, rather than addition.

Comment: Brilliant answer! Also updated my code for pascal triangle. I just wanted to make it short, somehow in one line.

Comment: @python Thanks! FWIW, you can shorten the main calculation in my code by using `sum`, but I doubt that it'd be more efficient, since it involves an extra function call: `row = [sum(t) for t in zip([0] + row, row + [0])]`